# Откуда взялась золотая рыбка

Tags: литература

Все мы знаем сказку Пушкина "О рыбаке о рыбке". Но, как известно, Пушкин свои сказки не сам выдумывал, а использовал в них уже существующие фольклорные сюжеты. И отзвуки многих его сказок легко можно найти как в западном фольклоре, так и в русском. Но вот меня интересует: откуда взялась волшебная рыбка? Что-то я не припомню фольклорных рыб и рыбаков (разве что Король-Рыбак). Есть ли какие-то сюжеты, которые легли в основу этой сказки?

Comment: А Щука, которую поймал Емеля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто придумал сказку

Где Пушкин взял сюжет «Сказки о рыбаке и рыбке» (1833)?  Вариантов несколько: 1) Это русская народная сказка, известная по записи в собрании А.Н.Афанасьева (1830). 2)Это немецкая сказка из сборника братьев Гримм.3. Это  древний сюжет, восходящий к к праславянским, скифским и сарматским древностям. В эпоху Великого переселения народов в первых веках нашей эры древнее предание о рыбке-волшебнице покидает пределы Северного Причерноморья. Века спустя мы встретим ее в немецких, шведских, французских, молдавских сказках.

Волшебный помощник

По классификации В.Я.Проппа («Морфология волшебной сказки», 1947), пушкинская золотая рыбка относится к особой разновидности сказочных героев — «волшебным помощникам». Сказочных «помощников», выполняющих волшебным образом желания героев и героинь, превеликое множество в произведениях мирового фольклора, но аналог золотой рыбке — божественной, неповторимой —среди них найти не удалось.

Портрет золотой рыбки

В сказке братьев Гримм в роли золотой рыбки выступает обычная камбала. Золотая рыбка выглядела иначе. Как же?Терракотовая фигурка из Северного Причерноморья I века до нашей эры дает отчетливое представление о воспетой поэтом обитательнице морских глубин. У терракотовой рыбки большие, почти идеально круглые глаза, прижатые к корпусу верхний и нижний плавники, передающие стремительное движение, и закругленный хвост. Корпус рыбки необычный, почти ромбический. Все вместе создает впечатление энергии, силы и вместе с тем — изящества, грации.

Это не просто рыбка

Существует древняя удивительная история о золотой рыбке и старике со старухой, в которой душа называется стариком, а ложное эго, или то, что нас заставляет отождествлять себя с материальным телом, называют старухой.

Богиня священных вод ("хочу быть владычицей морскою")

Среди  древностей, найденных  в Причерноморье, есть пластина, на которой изображена полуфигура женщины. Ее волосы распущены, на голове корона, а на уровне живота изображена рыба. Богиня Анахита (авест. могучая, беспорочная») хорошо известна в древнем Иране, Средней Азии, ее портрет дан в Авесте — древнейшем памятнике письменности ариев! «Дева прекрасная, сильная, стройная, высоко подпоясанная, прямая, знатного рода, благородного», Анахита  была хранительницей источника всемирных вод, стекающих с вершины первозданного горного кряжа в Божественном царстве Света. Древние арии верили, что священные воды эти дают начало всем водам и рекам на земле, питающим сады и поля, и поэтому богиня вод Анахита считалась у них также и покровительницей плодородия. У славян имя древней арийской богини священных вод было табуировано и заменялось эпитетом-иносказанием Мокошь, Мокрешь, Макуша.

http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/dara3/post300138781/